# Adjuntar varios archivos pdf para enviarlos por mail con Google Sheets app script

Tags: javascript, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Quiero enviar un email desde Google Sheets con datos adjuntos. En un rango de celdas de una hoja, tengo entre 3 y 5 celdas con un ID de los archivos de Google Drive en cada celda (ej. 1h35mf61GiyW6Ux-bPk8xb5k7-X5spbvJs). Con el xxx.getRange("E8:E13").getValue(); estoy intentando leer las celdas que tienen el "id" de los archivos (unas veces 2 y otras 4) y llevarlas al " var attachmentstring = values["id de los pdf en google drive"];", que es lo que no consigo.

A ver si alguien me podría ayudar.
Gracias!

```
    function createAndSendDocument(values) {

       // add the attachments variables
     var attachmentstring = values["id de los pdf en google drive"];
     var array = attachmentstring.toString().split(",");
     var blobs = [];
     var x = 0;
     for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

       //check if even
       if (i % 2 === 0) {

      }
     else 
      {
       blobs[x] = DriveApp.getFileById(array[i]).getBlob();
       x++;
    }

  }
    // an email body.
  var body = 'Hello';

  // Send an email with attachments
  GmailApp.sendEmail("email@gmail.com", "subject", body, {attachments: blobs});
 }
```